# Why Facebook deprecated offline_access and support access_tokens with a long-lived expiration time ?

Tags: facebook, oauth

What is the rationale for Facebook deprecated offline_access and support access_tokens with a long lived expiration time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale behind this decision is to ensure that the app is getting visited by its users for at least once in a 60 days.
In order to extend the user acces token , your app should get the short lived access token, which can be done when a user is **logged** in via your app, and then you can ask the graph api to extend it.

So with this extending procedure, Facebook ensures that the app is "doing" actions on behalf of its **active users**. If a user won't use your app for more than 60 days then your app won't be able to do actions on behalf of its **non-active** users.

However, notice that if you'll use app access token, which never expires, you'll be able to execute the actions even for a non-active user. Ofcourse you'll have to ask for special permissions and to use the "Real time updates" of Facebook.